# How to trigger multiple Jenkins jobs at same time in Python?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have one job setting up completely. It is working fine when I do one build at time from python.
In my scenario, my code have been deployed at multiples PCs. So, there might be chance where multiple builds trigger at same time. If it has happen only any one of the build is getting successful. I want to do every build after one by one.

I have gone through google but couldn't find the solution for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the job gets triggered multiple times at once, but you wnat each build to run one after the other instead of in parallel, you need to enable the option "disable concurrent buidls". This is if your job is a freestyle job. If it is a declarative pipeline, use:

```
options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}
```

This would "Disallow concurrent executions of the Pipeline. Can be useful for preventing simultaneous accesses to shared resources, etc.".

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by two ways

```
Goto your job -> configure -> General 
checked-in "Do not allow concurrent builds" (see snaps below)
```

OR

add the below code snippet in your pipeline (if your jenkins job is a pipeline job)

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages {
        stage('xyz'){
            steps {
                echo "do something"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Disabling concurrent builds means that new builds will queue up and wait for a running build to complete.**